# Identifying rotation of accelerometer using xyz values in Python

Tags: python, time-series, accelerometer

I have time series data consisting of x y z values of accelerometer readings. I want to be able to detect that the device was moved/rotated using these values in Python.

Following is a plot of such data -
[plot of xyz values of acclerometer data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q14p.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be helpful to know what specific part of this problem you are stuck on.

Comment: I took axis mean values - if the mean is drastically changing - I raise a flag. I want to know if there is a better approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

Using RMS is going to help you know if movement happened, but since you lose the individual axes values it becomes impossible to distinguish what kind of movement it is.

Movement in each direction is relatively simple as that will show up as an acceleration on that axis. For rotation, assuming you are near the earth, you will have a constant acceleration equal to -9.8m/s^2 toward the earth. As your sensor is rotated the distribution of that acceleration onto the different axes will change. That should become more clear if you look at something like an average across a period of time for each axis.

Comment: Hi - thank you. I have tried checking the average of axes values, it does seem to work. Needed to know if there is any other solution using Python.

Comment: If you mean that you are looking for a specific library to parse this kind of data - I was able to find this with some google searching: https://pypi.org/project/sensormotion/